# Weird illegal tkinter state when calling `widget.destroy` from a `widget.after` script

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was creating a simple program (a label that refreshes itself every 0.1 sec) but I ran into a problem. This is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk


def loop():
    global label
    # If the label exists, destroy it
    if label is not None:
        label.destroy()

    # Create a label
    label = tk.Label(root)
    label.pack() # You don't even need this line for the error

    # After some time call `loop` again
    label.after(100, loop)


label = None
root = tk.Tk()
# Start the loop
loop()
root.mainloop()
```

The error traceback shows:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 752, in callit
    self.deletecommand(name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 601, in deletecommand
    self._tclCommands.remove(name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

When I changed `label.after(...)`, into `root.after(...)` it worked. My guess is that `tkinter` goes in an illegal state after I call `label.destroy()` from the `label.after(...)` script. I don't know if the problem comes from `tkinter` or `_tkinter`.

Can anyone prove that that's causing problem or suggest another explanation?

PS: Python 3.7.9

Comment: The problem isn't from the Tcl side itself, but then Tcl doesn't bind `after` processing to any widget in the first place (it's instead a feature of the per-thread event management engine that powers the event loop). It's that binding — which is a part of Tkinter — that appears to be going weirdly wonky; I've no idea why. You've got a workaround. Also, it's best to try to avoid rebuilding widgets a lot; that's _very_ resource expensive! (It's OK for demonstrating a bug, though. Just don't do it in production if you don't have to.)

Comment: @DonalFellows Ok thanks for the info. I always try to get to the bottom of the bugs that I find. Also this was part of another stackoverflow user's code. I will remove the `tcl` tag and update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how or what or why is the problem but I think I fixed it (it doesn't throw an error at least) maybe it happens because the widget gets destroyed while it has the `.after` still affecting it or sth like that:

```
import tkinter as tk


def loop():
    global label
    # If the label exists, destroy it
    if label:
        label.after(0, label.destroy)

    # Create a label
    label = tk.Label(root)
    label.pack()  # You don't even need this line for the error

    # After some time call `loop` again
    label.after(100, loop)


label = None
root = tk.Tk()
# Start the loop
loop()
root.mainloop()
```

Another thing is that it manages to do exactly 2 full loops before throwing an error

Comment: My question is why that happens not a working solution. Note that a simpler solution is just to replace `label.after(...)` with `root.after(...)`

Comment: @TheLizzard well I can only explain it with what I mentioned in my answer but I think the other answer explains this better.